# Пример java ee

Tags: java-ee, java, база-данных, spring

Добрый день. Сейчас изучаю стек java технологий связанных с веб разработкой. Ищу пример проекта с использованием Spring, работой с БД, JSP и прочее сопутствующее с целью поразбираться в более-мение реальном коде. Подойдет например какой нибудь сайт с регистрацией, и данными привязанными к аккаунту с JSP фронтом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Вот вам рабочий проект](https://github.com/jtalks-org/jcommune). Полноценный форум с пользователями, регистрациями, админками, кэшами  и прочим.

Answer (score 2):

Вряд ли кто даст рабочий проект, но я рекомендую сделать поиск на Github: "Spring Hibernate". По этому поиску выдает много чего. Вот например [этот](https://github.com/jasoet/Spring-Hibernate)